# Verify if string is in array

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP page - and I made a unofficial API to my college's student management software. It provides me (on another server) with an array of all the students and their main classroom.

Everything works except for the fact that old and gradtuated students also is exported from my cURL API. I have 20 (or so) values that are the only ones that should be parsed.

Thank you so much!

---

UPDATE!
This is an example output of the full script:

```
{"id":"test1","name":"Test - 1w"}, {"id":"test2","name":"Testo - 2w"}, {"id":"IAmOdd","name":"I was in college last year - 14"}
```

The script for echoing the output is

```
{\"id\":\"$domid\",\"name\":\"$domout - $klasse\"},");
```

And again I wan't to remove the last post who has a $klasse value which is not in the array $classrooms.

---

**FINAL SOULUTION**

I ended up doing like this :

```
if (preg_match("/1a|1b|1c|1d|1e|1u|1s|1y|1x|1w|2a|2b|2c|2d|2e|2u|2s|2y|2x|2w|3a|3b|3c|3d|3e|3u|3s|3y|3x|3w/", $row['navn'])) {
$ok = 1; }
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo utf8_encode("{\"id\":\"$domid\",\"name\":\"$domout - $klasse\"},");
}
```

This is what I have for the verifying process right now:

```
$classrooms = array('1a','1b','1c','1d','1e','1u','1s','1y','1x','1w','2a','2b','2c','2d','2e','2u','2s','2y','2x','2w','3a','3b','3c','3d','3e','3u','3s','3y','3x','3w');
foreach ($classrooms as $bad) {
 if (strpos($mainclassroom, $bad) !== false) {
       $allow = 0;
 }
 else {
        $allow = 1;         
  }
}
```

Comment: I am actually looking for the exact opposite of in_array :)

Comment: You can easily reverse the in_array function in our "if"-clause by using a " == false" oder just a "!" ... `if ( in_array($needle, $haystack) == false)``

Comment: How does `in_array()` help if he is looking to match values in array against some string segment?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use an array_filter function here.

```
$filtered_classrooms = array_filter($classrooms, function($value) use $mainclassroom {
    return (strpos($mainclassroom, $value) === false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you actually have a list of words, that aren't supposed to be part of the input string. Then a regex would be most convenient:

```
$bad = preg_match('/1[a-x]|2[a-x]|3a|3b|3c|3d/', $mainclassroom);
```

You can of course list all classes individually instead of with letter ranges. Or make a list with [`implode("|", $array)`](http://php.net/implode) from your bad words list.

The problem with your code however simply was the overwriting of the `$allow=` variable in the if/else on *each* run of the foreach.